# Create multiple views in shell script or big query

Tags: python, google-bigquery, sh

When I am exporting data from MySQL to BigQuery, some data are been duplicated. As a way to fix this, I thought of creating views of this tables using row number. The query to do this is shown below. The problem is that a lot of tables in my dataset are duplicated and possibly when I add new tables and export them to big query, they will have duplicated data and I don't want to create this type of query every time that a I add a new table in my dataset (I want that, in the moment I export a new table, a view to this table is created). Is this possible to do in a loop in the query (like 'for each table in my data set, do this')? Is this possible to do in shell script (when export a table to big query, create a view for this table)? In last case, is this possible to do in python?

```
SELECT
  * EXCEPT (ROW_NUMBER)
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id order by updated_at desc) ROW_NUMBER
  FROM dataset1.table1
)
WHERE ROW_NUMBER = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely can be done in python.
I would recommend to use gcloud python library https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python

So I think you script should be something like this

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery import Dataset

client = bigquery.Client()

dataset_ref = client.dataset('dataset_name')
tables = list(client.list_tables(dataset_ref))

for tab in tables:
     table = dataset.table("v_{}".format(tab.name))
     table.view_query = "select * from `my-project.my.dataset.{}`".format(tab.name)
     #if creating legacy view comment out next line
     table.view_query_legacy_sql = False
     table.create()
```